# Strange issue while using XElement to remove a node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

So I have the following code in which I am using `XDocument` library to parse my `XML` and perform associated actions on the XML required.

Now while removing a node(s) under a particular block, I observed that it removes the ending tag of the block. Please refer to the working program here to demonstrate this behavior:

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmY01V

You will see that I am trying to remove the `lang` tags under the `hl1` element. It removes the `lang` tag successfully but also removes the `</hl1>` ending tag with it.

Why is this behavior happening?

The other question here is that how I can add ONE `lang` node under the `hl1` element with a new value and remove the multiple ones?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                            <!--<!DOCTYPE nitf SYSTEM 'nitf-3-4.dtd'>-->
                            <nitf>
                              <head>
                              </head>
                              <body>
                                <body.head>
                                  <hedline>
                                    <hl1 id='Headline1' class='1' style='Headline1' MainHead='true'>
                                      <lang class='3' style='Headline1' font='Patrika15' fontStyle='Bold' size='18'>राजस्थान:</lang>
                                      <lang class='3' style='Headline1' font='Patrika15' fontStyle='Bold' size='18'>ऑनलाइनऑफलाइन रजिस्ट्रेशन</lang>
                                    </hl1>
                                    <hl2 id='Headline2' class='1' style='Headline2' MainHead='false'>
                                      <lang class='3' style='Headline2' font='Patrika15' fontStyle='Bold' size='30'>53.15 लाख बच्चों को टीके लगाने के लिए 3456 केन्द्र</lang>
                                    </hl2>
                                    <hl2 id='Headline2' class='1' style='Headline2' MainHead='false'>
                                      <lang class='3' style='Headline2' font='Patrika15' fontStyle='Bold' size='30'>53.15 लाख बच्चों को टीके लगाने के लिए 3456 केन्द्र 12</lang>
                                    </hl2>
                                  </hedline>
                                  <summary></summary>
                                  <quotes>
                                    <quote></quote>
                                  </quotes>
                                </body.head>
                                <body.content id='Bodytext'>
                                </body.content>
                              </body>
                            </nitf>");

        var element = doc.XPathSelectElement("//hedline");
        int hl1=0;

        foreach (XNode node in element.Nodes())
        {
            if(node.ToString().Contains("<hl1"))
            {
                hl1++;
                string h1text=string.Empty;
                var x = node.XPathSelectElements("lang");
                int count = x.Count();
                var mylist = x.ToList();
                Console.WriteLine(doc);
                for(int i=0; i<count;i++)
                {
                    mylist[i].Remove();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(doc);     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Common issue when removing items from a list.  When you remove item 4 from list item 5 becomes item 4 and you skip removing items.  Best way of solving is moving from end of list towards beginning.   for (int i =  element.Nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--).  Then var e = element.Nodes[i]

Comment: @jdweng I tried this method and also tried using `linq` but same output. The `</hl1>` tag is always removed when it hits `.Remove()` method.

Comment: foreach (XElement ele in doc.Descendants("hl1")){ }   You do not need IF

Comment: The `<hl1>` element is not being removed.  Instead, once all the children of the the `<hl1>` element are removed, it gets converted to an **empty element**: i.e. `<hl1></hl1>` becomes `<hl1 />`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/FIpMhq.  As explained in [Why use an empty element in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29082189) these are semantically identical, so it appears LINQ to XML is using the `<hl1 />` purely for the sake of brevity.

Comment: If you don't want LINQ to XML to make the element empty, you can set `hl1Node.Value.SetValue("")` on an `IsEmpty` element to force a closing tag as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/462791) by [Steven Robbins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26507/steven-robbins) to [Explicit Element Closing Tags with System.Xml.Linq Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/462747/3744182).  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/KP2Uux.  In fact, if not a typo/not reproducible question, this might be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: @dbc I have followed your explanations and now things are clear to me so thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you remove the `lang` tags, the `hl1` tag converts to '`Self-Closing`' tag. It means `hl1` tag is an empty element. Anyway try below code to remove children of `hl1` tag and create new one.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"Your XML content");
        //var element = doc.XPathSelectElement("//hedline");
        //int hl1 = 0;

        foreach (XElement xElement in doc.Descendants("hl1"))
        {
            #region remove lang tags

            var langElements = xElement.XPathSelectElements("lang");
            langElements.Remove();

            #endregion
            #region create new element in this 'hl1' tag

            xElement.Add(CreateElement());

            #endregion
        }   
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
    private static XElement CreateElement()
    {
        XElement xe = new XElement("lang");
        xe.SetAttributeValue("class", 3);
        xe.SetAttributeValue("style", "Headline1");
        xe.SetAttributeValue("font", "Patrika15");
        xe.SetAttributeValue("fontStyle", "Bold");
        xe.SetAttributeValue("size", "18");
        xe.Value = "My Value";
        return xe;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to remove and recreate the `<hl1>` tag, you just need to do `hl1Node.Value.SetValue("")` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/462791) by [Steven Robbins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26507/steven-robbins) to [Explicit Element Closing Tags with System.Xml.Linq Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/462747/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Right, but he wanted to know how to remove and add an element, on other side I wanted to show how to set an attribute. If he just wanted to know how to change the value, he would probably ask his question differently!