# Recognize Xpath for EMPTY element

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Part of my XML is below, with the help of others I knew it is correct but just empty element.

It seems that I can use the Xpath for  and  to check their existence but when I use the Xpath for  or , it returns empty.

elements/attributes/tags etc has **"/"** in it

```
                        <securityConfigSMC>
                            <securityAlgorithmConfig>
                                <cipheringAlgorithm><nea2/></cipheringAlgorithm>
                                <integrityProtAlgorithm><nia2/></integrityProtAlgorithm>
                            </securityAlgorithmConfig>
                        </securityConfigSMC>
```

Comment: They are just empty elements and can be used in XPath.
See this question for some extra help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082189/why-use-an-empty-element-in-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever your problem is, it's not caused by the empty element tags such as `<nea/>`, which are perfectly correct XML.

It always helps to say what symptoms you are seeing (e.g. error messages, empty results) rather than just telling us that something doesn't work.